# Not getting access to admin panel in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.8

I have uploaded the Magento script on my domain,
but when I was making changes through the admin panel, my site stopped working.

and when i tried to login again into the admin panel nothing is getting displayed.
and also i am not getting any error in error log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible cause could be permission. You can check this.

Comment: sir am not getting access to admin panel also i checked all the permissions. Mysite is working but admin panel fails to work.what can i do for this.

Comment: check the allowed ip, restriction etc.